# Mobile version of site with additional screen for navigation

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a Joomla 2.5 site and I'm creating a mobile version of it. I want to use the same menus and same articles but adjust the content. For this I'm using a simple mobile detection plugin so it changes the stylesheet only. This all works fine.

However, I need an additional page that just contains the main menu. In Joomla you have a default page and this is currently my home page for both my desktop and mobile version. I want the mobile site to load my main menu page first then the user can navigate from there. Does anyone know of the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A site can only have one default page so you will need to redirect a user to the mobile menu page when they first visit the site. There's a couple of ways to do this would be to set a cookie indicating they have been to the main navigation or use session variables. In either case, you would need to add a plugin or code to the default page to determine if they need to be redirected or not.

That said, why not just make your template responsive. It's fairly easy to implement the Bootstrap framework (there are tons of templates already out there using Bootstrap) and then it is trivial to show or hide content based on the size of the screen the user has.

Comment: Thanks Brent - I ended up creating a new DIV for the navigation and toggling it on and off as required. This meant the pages could stay the say. Thanks for your help.